# Uc_product module for drupal 7 not found

Tags: commerce

In my Drupal 7 installation, i want to enable the ubercart feeds module but it says :"Requires: Uc_product (missing), Feeds (enabled), Chaos tools (enabled), Job Scheduler (enabled)" . The problem is i cannot find the uc_product module in the drupal website, or anywhere, any help?

Answer (score 1):

The uc_product module is part of the [Ubercart](https://www.drupal.org/project/ubercart) module.  Based on [drupal-commerce](/questions/tagged/drupal-commerce) you added as tag to the question, I assume you are using the Drupal Commerce module instead of the Ubercart module. In that case, uc_product wouldn't be useful, unless you switched over to using the Ubercart module.

The [Commerce Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_feeds) module would likely be more useful if you are really using the Drupal Commerce module.